# How to output iterate over first N elements of slice?

Tags: go, slice

I need to take applicant's first name, second name and GPA, then output only the first N applicants. For example, I have 5 applicants, but only N=3 can pass through.
To do this task, I decided to use a slice of struct.

The struct looks like this:

```
type Applicant struct {
    firstName  string
    secondName string
    GPA        float64
}
```

I created a slice and initialized it:

```
applicants := []Applicant{}
...
fmt.Scan(&firstName, &lastName, &GPA)
applicants = append(applicants, Applicant{firstName, lastName, GPA})
```

Now my task is to output only **names** of first 3 applicants with highest GPA. I already sorted the slice from the best GPA to the worst.

I tried to do output applicants slice like this, but got error:

```
for _, applicant := range applicants {
    fmt.Println(applicant.secondName + " " + applicant.secondName)
}
```

Can you help me with slice **name output**?

Comment: https://go.dev/tour/moretypes/7

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get the first 3 with highest GPA you first sort the slice (what you alread did) and then just create a subslice:

```golang
func GetTopThree(applicants []Applicant) []Applicant {
    sort.Slice(applicants, func(i, j int) bool {
        return applicants[i].GPA > applicants[j].GPA
    })
    return applicants[:3]
}
```

---

To just get the names you can create a new slice

```golang
func GetTopThreeNames(applicants []Applicant) []string {
    var topThree []string
    for i := 0; i < int(math.Min(3, float64(len(applicants)))); i++ {
        topThree = append(topThree, applicants[i].firstName)
    }
    return topThree
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that there can be index out-of-bounds errors if the slice is smaller than 3 elements.

Comment: Yeah, it works but i already have sorting algorithm, how can i initialise this new subslice only to first and last names  of highest GPA then?
The task was to output ONLY NAMES in order of highest GPA

Answer (score 1):

If you want to map the first names and last names separately, this could be an approach:

```golang
func TopThreeNames(applicants []Applicant) [][2]string {
    top := applicants[:int(math.Min(3, float64(len(applicants))))]

    var names [][2]string
    for _, a := range top {
        names = append(names, [2]string{a.firstName, a.secondName})
    }
    return names
}
```

The function maps each `Applicant` element to an array of length two, whereby the first element is equal to its first name and the second element to its second name.

For instance (unsafe since the length of the slice could be empty):

```golang
names := TopThreeNames(applicants)
    
first := names[0]
fmt.Printf("First name: %s and last name: %s\n", first[0], first[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

If your task really is just to print out the names then this is one possible way

```
  for i := 0; i < 3 && i < len(applicants); i++ {
        fmt.Printf("%s %s\n", applicants[i].firstName, applicants[i].secondName)
    }
```

Note that the list must be sorted first like is is shown in other posts.